# A partial ordering on $S_n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Where $P$ and $Q$ are permutations in $S_n$, let's say $P<Q$ if $P$ is obtained from $Q$ by swapping two numbers which $Q$ places in the correct order. For example, if

$$Q=(1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2)$$
$$P=(1,\textbf5,6,\textbf3,4,2)$$

then $P<Q$. We can make this into a partial order by taking the transitive closure. Is anything known about this partial order?

Comment: this is called the weak order on permutations (or weak Bruhat order), and a *lot* is known about it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Weak_order_of_permutations and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron to start.

Comment: I’m not sure it is weak order. It seems that according to the OP’s definition we would have $231 < 132$; but $231$ and $132$ are incomparable in weak order.

Comment: Actually, this is the strong Bruhat order, not the weak order.

Comment: @SamHopkins and Richard Stanley: thank you for the correction!